# Subdomain rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have the follow .htaccess and it work good.

from http://us.domain.org/detail.php?id=1234 to 
http://us.domain.org/category/city/computer-1234

but if I add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /detail.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It does not work..How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `from http://us.domain.org/detail.php?id=1234 to http://us.domain.org/category/city/computer-1234`

Change your last rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /detail.php?id=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: anubhava I need your help :) 
I need to add this rule but I dont know how to do..can you help me?
from  http://it.domain.org/index.php?city=newyork to http://it.domain.org/product-usa-newyork

The only thing that change is "newyork". It can be also: lasvegas etc..

Comment: Can you please create a new question with that problem and I will try my level best to test your new URI scheme and answer it.

Comment: I created, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889957/subdomains-rewrite-htaccess