# Subdomains rewrite .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these rules, everything work good.

I just need to add this rule:

from it.domain.org/index.php?city=newyork to it.domain.org/product-usa-newyork

The only thing that change is "newyork". It can be also: lasvegas etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting these 2 rules **before your existing rules**:

```
#Rewrite from http://it.domain.org/index.php?city=dc to http://it.domain.org/product-usa-dc
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /product-usa-%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^product-usa-([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?city=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it at the start

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /product-usa-%1 [R=302,L]
```